# Java AES cipher text size

Tags: java, cryptography, aes, block, encryption

I'm using a very standard way of Java AES encryption / decryption.

```
byte[] key = hexStringToByteArray("C0C1C2C3C4C5C6C7C8C9CACBCCCDCECF");

byte[] message = hexStringToByteArray("01A0A1A2A3A4A5A6A703020100060001");

SecretKeySpec secretKeySpec = new SecretKeySpec(key, "AES");

// Instantiate the cipher
Cipher cipher = Cipher.getInstance("AES");
cipher.init(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE, secretKeySpec);

byte[] encrypted = cipher.doFinal(message);

cipher.init(Cipher.DECRYPT_MODE, secretKeySpec);
byte[] original = cipher.doFinal(encrypted);
```

As you can see I'm using 128 bit key, and 128 bit message. I always pretty much get the result I expected, however, the encrypted result is always 256 bit long. The second 128 bits being always the same. Other than truncating the result, how can I ensure that the cipher returns only the first 128 bits, without changing the first 128 bits? I feel like I've got kind of mixed up with the definition of block size here.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

There are a couple of mandatory things to get out of the way before approaching your question. One thing that I see in this code that is potentially dangerous is that the cipher isn't specified with explicit mode and padding. This means it is up to the provider defaults. If this is the provider currently distributed with Oracle's JVM, those defaults are `ECB` and `PKCS5Padding`. If those are what you want to use then specify them this way:

```
 Cipher cipher = Cipher.getInstance("AES/ECB/PKCS5Padding");
```

The second is that `ECB` isn't a good choice of modes to use because it isn't very secure. `CBC` is a much better option since it makes use of an initialization vector.

On to the question. The reason for the size of the encrypted text is due to the padding scheme, in this case `PKCS5`. The padding is necessary to ensure that the plain text is of a length that the algorithm can handle. For AES, it must be a multiple of 16 bytes. In the case where the unencrypted data's length is already a multiple of 16 bytes, the padding must add an additional 16 bytes (see jbtule's comment here). Initializing the `Cipher` like this produces 16 bytes of encrypted data:

```
Cipher cipher = Cipher.getInstance("AES/ECB/NoPadding");
```

This requires that the unencrypted data is already a multiple of 16 bytes in length since it won't pad it at all. If it isn't, an exception is thrown.

It might be beneficial to understand exactly what you are trying to do to give a good recommendation.

Comment: Just to clarify your very correct answer, `PKCS5` padding will always add a full block pad when the ciphertext is exactly block size regardless of implementation. Otherwise how would you determine ciphertext from padding.

Comment: Right, that makes perfect sense.

Comment: I need it to work this way, I'm trying to use it  to encryypt CCM blocks, so the blocksize and the size of the encrypted data is always the same. The reason I need the default implementation is because I need to write some unit tests, and the seem to have used this cipher since, I get the exact same result. Thank you for your answer it did help me a lot!

Comment: You will probably want to consider using `CTR` with an initialization vector as mentioned by `Zim-Zam O'Pootertoot` since it can handle data of any length without the need for padding.

Answer (score 3):

Your cipher instance is using PKCS5Padding padding, which adds up to 16 bytes of padding to the ciphertext.  There are a couple of ways to correct this:

Option 1: Instead of using Cipher.getInstance("AES"), which uses padding, use Cipher.getInstance("AES/CBC/NoPadding").  This is NOT recommended, however, as it requires that the plaintext be a multiple of 16 bytes.

Option 2: Use [BouncyCastle](http://www.bouncycastle.org/java.html) as your crypto provider, and then use

```
import org.bouncycastle.jce.provider.BouncyCastleProvider;
Cipher.getInstance("AES/CTR/NoPadding", new BouncyCastleProvider());
```

to initialize the cipher.  This uses Counter mode (CTR) instead of Cipher Block Chaining mode (CBC), and Counter mode does not require any padding.  With Counter mode it is important that you use a unique initialization vector, which can be transmitted in plaintext along with the ciphertext; for example,

```
byte[] IV = new byte[16];
new SecureRandom().getBytes(IV);
cipher.init(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE, key, IV);
```

Then when decrypting the ciphertext, initialize the cipher with the same initialization vector.  It is up to you how you transmit the IV, but again, it does not need to be kept secret.

The initialization vector for Cipher Block Chaining mode should also be unique, but this is not as critical as it is for Counter mode.

Comment: Using BouncyCastle isn't required to use `CTR`, so this would work even with Oracle's provider.