# JAVA AES-encryption padding

Tags: java, aes, padding

I'm using following peace of code to encrypt some data in my program:

```
cipher = Cipher.getInstance("AES/CBC/NoPadding");
cipher.init(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE, new SecretKeySpec(rawCipherKey, "AES"), new IvParameterSpec(rawCipherIV));
```

and then in another method:

```
try {
   cipher.doFinal(buffer, 0, len, encryptedBuffer, 12);
} catch (Exception e) {
   throw new RuntimeException(e);
}
```

The doFinal is throwing an exception:

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: javax.crypto.IllegalBlockSizeException: data not block size aligned
```

But this is **NOT** the problem and I understand the reason for that.

I have get following instructions for encrypting the data:

> Encrypt data, but only complete 16 byte blocks, the
>   rest stays unencrypted

Who can tell me if there is another way eg. for the

```
Cipher.getInstance("AES/CBC/DO_PADDING_BUT_ONLY_16_BYTES_AND_LEAVE_REST_UNENCRYPTED");
```

or how I can achieve this?

Comment: Does this help? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15880901/java-aes-cipher-text-size

Comment: Hello Peter, many thanks for the link. I will have a look at this. I think I have to do Ducans way.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no padding scheme that will support what you want.

Instead, dissect your data prior to encryption. Take as many blocks of data as are available and encrypt that, before appending the remaining plaintext.

Comment: Hello Ducan, yes I thought that I have to do it this way :) Many thanks for your answer!